# Problem with Cyrillic symbols on the Code of Conduct page of ruSO

Tags: bug, design, localization, russian-stackoverflow, code-of-conduct

There is a problem with the font on the Code of Conduct page of ruSO. As you can see below, the font quite different.

[English CoC](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct):

[image]

[Russian CoC](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct):

[image]

As I can see, [original font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Slab) contains Cyrillic symbols. But [SO version](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Fonts/roboto-slab/roboto-slab-bold-webfont.woff?v=719d1c709127) doesn't, so the browser has to fall back to a local system font for the characters that aren't in the web font.

Could you update the font in CDN, so it looks and feels the same on Eng and Rus pages?

Original question on ruSO: [Шрифт на странице норм поведения отличается от оригинального](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7660)

**UPD 08 March 2024:**

The problem is still actual.

Looks like for the headers fallback is `serif` but might be changed to `sans-serif` which is more suitable for the page.

```css
.p-ff-roboto-slab {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab',serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Alternatively the font Roboto Slab can be [updated from Google](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Slab). Looks like it supports Cyrillic symbols there.

Comment: Could you be more clear about what's the problem, exactly? I have only a very basic understanding of Russian but I can read it (though I don't understand some of the words, obviously).

Comment: @Glorfindel the problem here is that fonts are different. It's not about the text content itself.

Comment: @Glorfindel if I understand it correctly, the Roboto Slab webfont on the SE CDN that is supposed to be used there doesn't contain cyrillic characters. What the browser does according to the dev tools is to fall back to a local system font for the characters that aren't in the web font.

Comment: @MadScientist exactly.

Comment: [It supports it](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Slab?selection.family=Roboto+Slab) originally

Comment: @vp_arth official version yes, but SO uses different version..

Comment: @Glorfindel any updates?

Comment: Heh, I'm not working for Stack Overflow so I don't have any updates :)

Comment: @Glorfindel oh, sorry. So, basically, this thread was ignored by SE employees =/

Comment: @Suvitruf Я не знаю.

Comment: @Glorfindel :D thanks, anyways